# Unable to get Image from Amazon s3 through TransferUtility in android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am using transferutility mehtod in android to download image from amazon s3 bucket. Uploading is working fine. But in downloading it gives me an error while the image is in the bucket with the same key i am providing.

```
E/error: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: D1B5ACBA8389A6), S3 Extended Request ID: RnoeOgB1TC2AY7AZ+TiMK6C49yUpBcebX2wV0CA6Zy2kl20MTzq+Odo+PLLiBN4a=
```

My code to download image is:

```
credentialsProvider();
TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client, getApplicationContext());
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + test_object.getImagesQuestions().get(i).getImageKey());
                                        test_object.getImagesQuestions().get(i).setImage(file);
TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download(
                            "BucketName",     /* The bucket to upload to */
                             test_object.getImagesQuestions().get(i).getImageKey(),    /* The key for the uploaded object */
                             test_object.getImagesQuestions().get(i).getImage()       /* The file where the data to upload exists */
                             );
transferObserverListener(observer);
```

Comment: Looks like something wrong with image, key or the value as you are getting 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem. Actually there are multiple images downloading from s3. And after that download functions execute it runs in background until all the images download. and i have a code ahead which set images in the imageview. So the problem is that images are not yet download and code to display them run before. Thats why i was not getting any Image.